# Equivalence of norms: existence of a global constant?

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Any two norms $\|\cdot\|_p$ and $\|\cdot\|_q$ on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ are equivalent which means that there exist constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that
$$C_1\|\cdot\|_q \leq \|\cdot\|_p \leq C_2 \|\cdot\|_q$$
and vice versa
$$C_1'\|\cdot\|_p \leq \|\cdot\|_q \leq C_2' \|\cdot\|_p$$
for (potentially?) different constants $C_1'$ and $C_2'$.

Suppose I tell you that $\|v\|_p \leq K$ for some $v \in V$ and arbitrary choice of norm $\|\cdot\|_p$.

Does there exist a global constant $\mathcal{G}$ depending only on $V$ such that

$$\|v\|_r \leq  \mathcal{G}\, K$$
for all possible choices of norm $\|\cdot\|_r$ on $V$ ?

Comment: If you mean general norms, you might prefer to use $a,b,c$ for the suffix, rather than $p,q,r$ because $\|\cdot\|_p$ usually means the norm $$\left(|v_1|^p+\cdots+|v_n|^p\right)^{1/p}$$

Comment: It's fine. Your comment can serve as clarification. I have been careful to write "arbitrary", "any" and "all" everywhere to imply general norms.

Comment: Given a norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ we can take any constant $G >0$ and define a norm $$\|w\|_{p’} =G\|w\|_p$$ So you can’t find such $\mathcal G.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ we can take any constant $G >0$ and define a norm $$\|w\|_{p’} =G\|w\|_p$$ So you can’t find such $\mathcal G.$